# Difference between Singleton class and singleton method?

Tags: singleton

I have one question.

What is the difference between singleton class and singleton method.  I have created shared instance method,  if I use alloc method, it will create new instance or not?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Update your question with relevant code and clearly explain what your question is referring to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "singleton pattern" (or a "singleton class" or just "singleton") is simply any class for which you are only allowed a single instance.

A "singleton method" would refer to the method that one writes to access the instance. (Nowadays, in Swift and Objective-C, the public interface  would declare a property to access the singleton, not a method, but the idea is the same.)

Conventionally the "singleton pattern" refers to a class that simply would not permit the creation of additional instances. But it should be noted that the term "singleton" is sometimes used more loosely in those cases where there exists a single shared instance, but for which you may actually permit creation of your own instances, too. An example of that would be `NSURLSession`, whose `sharedSession` property is referred to as a "singleton" in the Apple documentation, but one is still permitted to create ones' own custom `NSURLSession` sessions.

Bottom line, whether you design your singleton in such a manner that you can or cannot instantiate additional instances is a question of the design of your class. (Many assiduously insist that this is the very meaning of "singleton". I'm not going to participate in that debate.) In many cases, we explicitly want to want to prevent the accidental creation instances. In other (more rare) cases, though, you may want to permit both a singleton as well as the ability to create additional instances. It's just a question of the intent of the singleton's class.

---

Note, your question was originally tagged [objective-c](/questions/tagged/objective-c). An Objective-C implementation might look as follows:

```
NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN

@interface Foo : NSObject

@property (class, strong, readonly) Foo *sharedFoo;

- (instancetype)init __attribute__((unavailable("Use +[Foo sharedFoo] instead")));
+ (instancetype)new __attribute__((unavailable("Use +[Foo sharedFoo] instead")));

@end

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END
```

And

```
@implementation Foo

+ (Foo *)sharedFoo {
    static Foo *sharedFoo = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedFoo = [[self alloc] init];
    });
    return sharedFoo;
}

- (id)init {
    if ((self = [super init])) {
        // do additional initialization here
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

Note:

1. Nowadays one would generally define the singleton to be accessed through a `@property` in the public interface, not as a method. This property would be declared as `class` and `readonly`, and you would then manually implement the getter accessor method for that property.

   By defining this public interface to be a property rather than a method, should you ever interface with this object via Swift, you will be accessing it using patterns more common in Swift. You don't *have* to define it as a property, but you generally would.
2. Note that I defined this property to be `sharedFoo`, rather than `sharedInstance` or `sharedManager`. By calling it `sharedFoo`, when you bridge this code with Swift, it will automatically be exposed as `shared`, the more concise name that Swift, as a matter of convention, uses for its singletons and other shared instances.
3. In this case I have declared `init` and `new` as `unavailable`. This will prevent developers from accidentally instantiating additional instances. Again, this is a question of the purpose of the singleton.

If you look at singletons (or other shared instances) throughout the Cocoa API, you'll see that Apple has transitioned to this property approach.

Comment: @hari-c please consider accepting this as answer. Better explained hence plus one :)